# Sync between local server and remote server using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a database in the localhost running with xampp. I have another database running in the hostgator. I need to synchronize these databases when a user presses a button. How to do this in php or is there an alternative? I tried data replication in phpmyadmin but there is no such replication tab in hostgator. I am stuck please help

Comment: Maybe what you mean is a backup? You can back it up from Hostgator cpanel.

Comment: I want it to happen with a button click

Comment: I am afraid you may not be able to achieve this. See if there is any `API` that Hostgator provides.